# Problems filtering a query in Node.js for MongoDB 6.0.6

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have this collection in MongoDB Atlas 6.0.6:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "646e55a6720656eee25e67cf",
    "game": "feedTheDemo",
    "leaderboard": [
      {
        "userId": "asdaba",
        "bestVictoryTime": 360
      },
      {
        "userId": "6460cec4618d335c032a7dc6",
        "bestVictoryTime": 123
      },
      {
        "userId": "2d2d2d",
        "bestVictoryTime": 242
      },
      {
        "userId": "asdad",
        "bestVictoryTime": 41
      },
      {
        "userId": "asd22222",
        "bestVictoryTime": 2414
      },
      {
        "userId": "242414",
        "bestVictoryTime": 12
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": "646e51fe517a1ed93699b9ca",
    "game": "otherGame",
    "leaderboard": [
      {
        "userId": "abrbueba",
        "bestVictoryTime": 12
      },
      {
        "userId": "6460cec4618d335c032a7dc6",
        "bestVictoryTime": 182
      },
      {
        "userId": "2d212",
        "bestVictoryTime": 124
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I can achieve in the playground that doing this:

```
db.collection.find({
  game: "feedTheDemo",
  "leaderboard.userId": "6460cec4618d335c032a7dc6"
},
{
  leaderboard: {
    $elemMatch: {
      userId: "6460cec4618d335c032a7dc6"
    }
  }
})
```

I obtain what I want:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "646e55a6720656eee25e67cf",
    "leaderboard": [
      {
        "bestVictoryTime": "00:00:03",
        "userId": "6460cec4618d335c032a7dc6"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

My problem is when I try to move this to my node.js server. I have this endpoint:

```
// Get user leaderboard info for a game
router.get("/game/:gameName/user/:userId", async (req, res) => {
  console.log("[ENDPOINT] Get user leaderboard info for the game: " + req.params.gameName + " and the user: " + req.params.userId);

  const query = {
    game: req.params.gameName,
    "leaderboard.userId": req.params.userId
  };

  const projection = {
    leaderboard: { $elemMatch: { userId: req.params.userId } }
  };

  let collection = db.collection(databaseProperties.GAME_LEADERBOARDS);
  let result = await collection.findOne(query, projection);

  console.log("THE RESULT FOR GET USER LEADERBOARD INFO FOR A GAME: " + JSON.stringify(result, null, 4))

  if (!result || result.length === 0) {
    res.status(404).send("Not found");
  } else {
    res.status(200).send(result.leaderboard);
  }
});
```

I tried for the result with collection.find too, trying to convert it to an array with .toArray() and getting the first value, but my problem is always the same, I obtain all the info of the collection with "game" = "feedTheDemo", but is not filtering by the leaderboard.userId, and less applying the projection for the same $elemMatch. I tried the other questions related here but I really can't understand the problem. Anyone has any clue?

Thanks in advance

I want to obtain just the documents that match the query, projected with the info of the leaderboard.userId, not the rest of info.

I tried with $filter, with $elemMatch, with find, findOne, etc.

All returns just the Collection document itself, but not filtered by nothing.